# Getting Excel to Conditionally Copy Data to Another Sheet

Tags: conditional-formatting, microsoft-excel-2016, parsing

I have a spread sheet that will have new data entries on each row. I need to get excel to automatically check for a specific column's value, and if that value is a 1, it needs to go to the sheet with the same title as the column. See this below image for an example;

[image: Example]
([larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1m2lP.png))

So there are 6 columns I need this check done on, basically. OUT_O_10, OUT_10_20, and so on, you see in the image. If the column OUT_O_10 has a 1 on it in the first sheet, I need the row, columns A through H only, copied to the next available row on the sheet also titled OUT_0_10.

[This link](http://excelenthusiasts.sharepoint.com/Documents/split-data-across-sheets.xls) will let you download a near-perfect example of what I want to do. Just like this spread sheet can check the "Department" column and move the rows to the sheet that has the corresponding title, I need my spreadsheet to check each of the columns that has the word "OUT" in it for a value of 1, and if there is a 1, move the row (columns A through H only) to the sheet with the same "OUT" title.

Please let me know if this is not clear. There must be a way to do it automatically though, as this sheet does exactly what I need mine to do, just can't figure out how to do it myself on my sheet. I do have excel 2016.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: I've tried migrating the method used in the example sheet from that sheet to mine to no avail. I've tried searching all over the web to find a tutorial on how to do this or find someone who's achieved practically exactly what I want for an easy migration from their sheet to mine and the one I linked is the closest I could get. I don't know what else to try. Sorry, I'm going to need someone who knows what they're doing to come in and either A. try their hand at this if they've never done it before, or B. tell me how to do it if they've already done it.

Comment: That would be convenient, but unfortunately this site does not work that way. We are all volunteers here who are willing to help, but we are not going to do it for you.

Comment: "This site does not work that way."

No, YOU don't work that way. There are some people who do work that way and are on this site, and will do the work for people like me who don't know what they're doing. I used the site before and have ran into some people like that. Don't act like your reluctance to do someone else's work applies to every single person on the site. I understand this isn't your task and you don't have to do all of it, which is totally cool, but it's not very fair of you to assume there's no one on the site willing to do it.